# Trying to scrape, getting [] back

Tags: python, scrapy

I am using `Scrapy 1.5.1` with `Python 2.7.6`. I am trying to scrape the usernames from the following [page](https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=1).

I have implemented the following code:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import scrapy
from scrapy.http import Request


class BtctalkspiderSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'btctalkSpider'
    allowed_domains = ['bitcointalk.org']
    max_uid = 10

    def parse(self, response):
        urls = response.xpath("//a/@href").extract()
        for i in range(self.max_uid):
            # scrapy shell "https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=1"
            yield Request('https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=%d' % i, callback=self.parse_application)

    def parse_application(self, response):
        userName = response.xpath('//td[normalize-space(.)="Name:"]/following-sibling::td/text()').extract()


        yield {
            'userName': userName
        }
```

However, when trying to scrape the site I am getting `[]` back.

I checked my `xpath` via the shell and everything seems to work.

Any suggestions what I am doing wrong?

Comment: you're scraping (scrape), not scrapping (scrap).

Comment: @AnttiHaapala Thx for your reply! Any suggestion why I get `[]`  back?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Some of the profiles urls simply doesn't exists, so XPath expression evaluated to nothing.

for ex: https://bitcointalk.org/index.php?action=profile;u=2

But, also, You need to specify a start url for ex: `start_urls = ['https://bitcointalk.org']` or just add `start_requests` function.

Here is a quote from Scrapy docs regarding `start_urls`[1](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/intro/tutorial.html?highlight=start_requests#a-shortcut-to-the-start-requests-method)...

> Instead of implementing a start_requests() method that generates
>   scrapy. Request objects from URLs, you can just define a start_urls
>   class attribute with a list of URLs.

Comment: Thx for your reply! Any suggestion why I get for `profile;u=1` nothing back?

Comment: You need to specify a start url `start_urls = ['https://bitcointalk.org']` or just add `start_requests` function.